# Static variable bug in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, testing, static

I have written a simple class and 3 tests as follows:

### Person.java:

```
package MyPackage;

public class Person {
    
    private static int PERSON_COUNTER = 0;
    
    public Person() {
        PERSON_COUNTER++;
    }
    
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
    
    public String helloName(String name) {
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
    
    public static int numberOfPersons() {
        return PERSON_COUNTER;
    }
    
}
```

---

**PersonTest.java:**

---

```
package Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

import MyPackage.Person;

public class PersonTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testHello() {
        Person p = new Person();
        assertEquals("Hello World",p.hello());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testHelloName() {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        assertEquals("Hello Mile",p1.helloName("Mile"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void numberOfPersons() {
        Person p2 = new Person();
        Person p3 = new Person();
        Person p4 = new Person();
        assertEquals(3, Person.numberOfPersons());
    }
}
```

The test numberOfPersons fails with message: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<4>
The fourth object person is being counted from testHello test and I don't seem to find reason why is that happening.

Comment: Do you realise that `testHello` and `testHelloName` also create `Person`s?

Comment: Yes I do but why it isn't 5 then, why only testHello increases static variable?

Comment: Do you realise that JUnit could run your tests in any order?

Comment: No I did not, thank you, I need to run the tests separately.

Comment: This kind of effect is _exactly why_ static state is nearly always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a method with the annotation @BeforeEach, that cleans your environment by resetting the variables, I think this  is what you are missing.